# Supercharger Extension for Visual Studio 2015 Always Disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I use the Supercharger extension in VS-2015, however after awhile the extension is always disabled on startup of the IDE.

[image: Screenshot of VS-2015 Extensions and Updates Window]

I use multiple instances of Visual Studio at a time, and for each instance I have to manually open extensions and Enable the extension, which forces me to restart that instance of VS.

Any ideas on what the issue is?

I am using VS-2015 version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3 on Windows 10 x64 Home version 1607 build 14393.321

I cannot find any entries in the windows event log or in the VS activity log.

Comment: This is not limited to Supercharger - it happens with other extensions too

Answer (score 2):

So it seems to only really become an issue if you are using multiple instances of Visual Studio 2015, and may be related to the extensions updating themselves.

It seems that multiple versions of the extensions get installed and this confuses Visual Studio.

The fix is to remove the extensions directly from the file system and then re-install them - if anyone has a better method please let me know?

**Step 1** - Close all instances of Visual Studio

Alt+F4

**Step 2** - Locate the Extensions folder for your account

Open the Extensions folder in the users AppData

> %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions

**Step 3** - Locate duplicate extensions

Check each of the folders in the Extensions folder. As per screenshot below, you will note that some extensions are duplicated in these folders.

As per screenshot below, I have duplicates of Paket and Supercharger.

[image: Screenshot of Extensions folder and duplicate sub-folders]

**Step 4** - Remove Extensions

For each extension that is duplicated, delete all folders containing that extension. This will completely remove that Extension from your account. Don't leave a single copy of the Extension as this seems to cause issues later.

Also remove the extension cache files (highlighted in yellow in screenshot above)

**Step 5** - Re-install Extensions

You should now open a single instance of Visual Studio 2015 and re-install the deleted extensions.

**Finally**

This bug seems to reoccur if you constantly use multiple instances of Visual Studio, so you may have to do this again and again until Microsoft addresses the bug.